# Relationship refuses to generate in Neo4j

Tags: database, neo4j

Ive been trying to generate a relationship between two already existing nodes using a csv file, the code looks like this:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "major.csv" AS row
MATCH(std:students {snum:toInteger(row.snum)})
MATCH (deg:degrees {name:row.name, level:row.level})
CREATE (std)-[:major]->(deg);
```

where students and degrees are already created. But for some reason there aren't relationships being created. Any help would be appreciated!!

Creating students:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "students.csv" AS row
CREATE(std:students {
    snum:toInteger(row.snum),
    ssn:toInteger(row.ssn),
    name:row.name,
    gender:row.gender,
    dob:row.dob,
    c_addr:row.c_addr,
    c_phone:row.c_phone,
    p_addr:row.p_addr,
    p_phone:row.p_phone
});
```

Creating degrees:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "degrees.csv" AS row
CREATE (dgr:degrees {
    name:row.name,
    level:row.level
});
```

I have spent ages looking up stuff online and couldn't find anything that fixed it. I got a relationship out of something I tried, but it wasn't the correct one, so I couldn't query anything from one node to another.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "major.csv" AS row
CREATE(maj:major)
WITH maj, row
MATCH (std: students {snum:toInteger(row.snum)})
CREATE (std)-[:major]->(maj)
WITH maj, row
MATCH (deg: degrees {name:row.name, level:row.level})
CREATE (deg)-[:administers]->(maj);
```

This just added a relationship from the student to a random node called major with only an id

Comment: Please give us a sample of your three csv files. So that we can try it out as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your data, my hunch is that one of the `MATCH` clauses does not find the node. In that case, we would silently not create any relationship.

You could try to test this theory by using `OPTIONAL MATCH` instead. Then, we always produce at least one binding of the node variable and may it be `null`. In that case, the query would fail and tell you which node it could not find.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are able to find a student using `row.snum`, it looks like you are not able to find degrees using `row.name` and `row.level` from "major.csv".

Check for differences between "degrees.csv" and "major.csv" in their `name` and `level` values. Perhaps the values are formatted differently, or perhaps the 2 files just have no overlapping degree data.